# How to store data in cloud and How to access data from cloud by using HTTP api?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Sorry for my English(I am not good in english please excuse).

I am working as a android application developer.I try to developing one application with backend support that means i want to use (web services) inside of the application.For that one i am trying to use google cloud for storing my data and access that data in json formt.It is possible to use that cloud data inside of my application.

For storing data in cloud they charge me something?

Please any one help me experts....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

At the onset, what you are trying to do is possible within App Engine. To summarise, you want to access some of your data that is stored using one or more of the available choices in the Google Cloud Platform and expose that over a Web Service running in your App Engine app.

- When it comes to exposing your existing functionality over REST+JSON, Google Cloud Endpoints is a great way to get started, though nothing prevents you from rolling out your own.
- For storage, there are several options and while you need to be mindful of the quotas/pricing, a great deal depends on which mechanism you want to employ as far as your storage API is concerned

  - Google Datastore API and Blobstore : The Google Datastore API is a non-relational database. The Blobstore is for storing large amounts of data (think images/videos). You have a free quota of 1GB for Datastore and 5GB for Blobstore within your App Engine application quota.
  - [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-sql/) : If you want to use a relational database , you can use Google Cloud SQL too. The pricing is mentioned on the page.
  - [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage/) : This is another storage option available with a Java client API. The pricing is mentioned on the page.
  - Google Drive : If your application is more of a personal nature and you wish to store some data within a Google Drive account of the user, you could look at that too.

Keep in mind that all these options are available as part of the [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/).

Hope this helps.